# Create dictionary based on matrix data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following CSV data frame imported using pandas (the numeric values are distances)

```
Forest,Bell Bay,Surrey Hills,Smithton,Hobart
Coupe 1,158,194,10,49
Coupe 2,156,169,71,84
Coupe 3,10,186,101,163
Coupe 4,47,94,134,139
Coupe 5,144,61,135,56
Coupe 6,27,27,134,36
Coupe 7,114,4,143,113
Coupe 8,71,170,190,140
Coupe 9,94,54,73,128
Coupe 10,46,194,92,36
```

By using the following code

```
df= pd.read_csv("Example.csv", header=0, index_col="Forest")
```

I created a list of forests I using:

```
I = df.index.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['Coupe 1', 'Coupe 2', 'Coupe 3', 'Coupe 4', 'Coupe 5', 'Coupe 6', 'Coupe 7', 'Coupe 8', 'Coupe 9', 'Coupe 10']
```

And a list of destinations J using:

```
J = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['Bell Bay', 'Surrey Hills', 'Smithton', 'Hobart']
```

The listed of tuples (arcs) was created using:

```
arcs = [(i, j) for i in I for j in J]
```

Result:

```
[('Coupe 1', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 1', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 1', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 1', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 2', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 2', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 2', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 2', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 3', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 3', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 3', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 3', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 4', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 4', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 4', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 4', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 5', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 5', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 5', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 5', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 6', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 6', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 6', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 6', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 7', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 7', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 7', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 7', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 8', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 8', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 8', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 8', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 9', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 9', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 9', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 9', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 10', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 10', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 10', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 10', 'Hobart')]
```

Next, I want to create a dictionary of arcs and distance values of the following type:

```
{('Coupe 1', 'Bell Bay'): 158, ('Coupe 1', 'Surrey Hills'):194, .....}
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to formulate this dictionary?
This is only a small set of I(10) and J(4) in a combined matrix. My methods have to be applicable to very large datasets with over 10 million I*J combinations.
Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex` first and then convert to dictionary by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.stack().to_dict()
```

---

```
print (d)
{('Coupe 1', 'Bell Bay'): 158, ('Coupe 1', 'Surrey Hills'): 194, ('Coupe 1', 'Smithton'): 10, ('Coupe 1', 'Hobart'): 49, ('Coupe 2', 'Bell Bay'): 156, ('Coupe 2', 'Surrey Hills'): 169, ('Coupe 2', 'Smithton'): 71, ('Coupe 2', 'Hobart'): 84, ('Coupe 3', 'Bell Bay'): 10, ('Coupe 3', 'Surrey Hills'): 186, ('Coupe 3', 'Smithton'): 101, ('Coupe 3', 'Hobart'): 163, ('Coupe 4', 'Bell Bay'): 47, ('Coupe 4', 'Surrey Hills'): 94, ('Coupe 4', 'Smithton'): 134, ('Coupe 4', 'Hobart'): 139, ('Coupe 5', 'Bell Bay'): 144, ('Coupe 5', 'Surrey Hills'): 61, ('Coupe 5', 'Smithton'): 135, ('Coupe 5', 'Hobart'): 56, ('Coupe 6', 'Bell Bay'): 27, ('Coupe 6', 'Surrey Hills'): 27, ('Coupe 6', 'Smithton'): 134, ('Coupe 6', 'Hobart'): 36, ('Coupe 7', 'Bell Bay'): 114, ('Coupe 7', 'Surrey Hills'): 4, ('Coupe 7', 'Smithton'): 143, ('Coupe 7', 'Hobart'): 113, ('Coupe 8', 'Bell Bay'): 71, ('Coupe 8', 'Surrey Hills'): 170, ('Coupe 8', 'Smithton'): 190, ('Coupe 8', 'Hobart'): 140, ('Coupe 9', 'Bell Bay'): 94, ('Coupe 9', 'Surrey Hills'): 54, ('Coupe 9', 'Smithton'): 73, ('Coupe 9', 'Hobart'): 128, ('Coupe 10', 'Bell Bay'): 46, ('Coupe 10', 'Surrey Hills'): 194, ('Coupe 10', 'Smithton'): 92, ('Coupe 10', 'Hobart'): 36}
```

Your solution is possible by dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
I = df.index.tolist()
J = df.columns.values.tolist()

arcs = {(i, j):df.loc[i, j] for i in I for j in J}
```

Comment: I guess we need `df.set_index('Forest').stack().to_dict()`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - No, because `I = df.index.tolist()` return `Forest`s values

Comment: Oh, sorry i didn't see while reading the dataframe OP has set index to already.

Comment: To clarify this:
```d``` created the dictionary and ```arcs``` recreated the same dictionary but has now been indexed with the column and row names?
How do I call my distance value in ```arcs```?

Comment: @SamVanHolsbeeck - It is same, I only called `dictioanry` like `d` ;)

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to loop over all your tuples from

```
arcs = [(i, j) for i in I for j in J]
```

and access each value by using pandas DataFrame's loc method

```
dictionary = {}
for forest_tuple in arcs:
    dictionary[(arcs[0], arcs[1])] = df.loc[arcs[0], arcs[1]]
```

which will return the dictionary you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this approach works for over 10 million entries or if its fast enough, but you could try the following:

```
dict = {}
for combination in arcs:
    dict[combination] = df.loc[combination[0], combination[1]]

print(dict)
```